# How to connect to dbeaver using Docker in Windows 10 environment?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, window

I am studying docker.

but i have a issue. because I can't see the db using dbeaver.

when you are using previous Linux, i could write the same and then it is working

but now i use window so not working

i made docker compose file

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      # network: auth-module

    volumes:
      - ./src:/server/src
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
    env_file:
      - ./.env.dev
    # command: "npm run prod"
    links:
      - postgres
  postgres:
    image: postgres:12
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USERNAME: "postgres"
      POSTGRES_DB: "auth"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "1234"
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: auth-module
```

What is the problem?

and How to fix it?

Comment: What _is_ the problem?  Is there an error message you're getting or some other problem you're running into?  Is just running `docker-compose up` enough to demonstrate it, or do you need some other commands?

Comment: i just use docker-compose up

i think the error is host problem

I can't even connect to the local host.